# Rails 4: append partial to hidden div upon AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `Post` and a `Comment` models.

A post `has_many` comments and a comment `belong_to` a post.

A user can create a new comment with a form on the post `show.html.erb` view:

```
<h2 class="center">COMMENT ON THIS POST</h2>
        <%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
          <p>
            <%= f.text_area :body, id: 'new_comment_body', placeholder: "Write your comment here..." %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <%= f.submit "CREATE COMMENT", id: 'comment_submit' %>
          </p>
        <% end %>
```

Here is my `comments_controllers.rb`:

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

With an AJAX call, I am capable of adding the newly created comment to the page:

```
# comments/create.js.erb

$('#post_show_comments').append("<%= j render @comment %>");
```

The problem is that, if a post has no comment yet, the `#post_show_comments` div is not displayed:

```
<% if @post.comments.any? %>
  <hr>
  <h2 class="center">COMMENTS</h2>
    <div id="post_show_comments">
      <%= render @comments %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Because of this, when the first comment of a post is created, it is not appended to the div, and the user needs to reload the page manually to see the comment appear.

How can I modify the content of `comments/create.js.erb` file to show the `#post_show_comments` div if there is no comment yet, and then append a new comment?

Comment: Can you use jquery to show the div prior to appending the comment? Something like $("#post_show_comments).show();

Comment: Sure. Should I insert this line of code in my `comments/create.js.erb` before   `$('#post_show_comments').append("<%= j render @comment %>");`? Also, should I implement any conditional to check if the div is already shown or not?

Comment: I actually tried just that (what I mention in my comment) and it does not work yet.

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: I just updated the question with the code from my controller. But I am not sure the problem comes from the controller, since everything is working fine when a post already has a comment (and therefore, the `#post_show_comments` is displayed). I guess the issue comes from the JS code, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of what OscuroAA suggested

```
<div id="post_show_comments_wrapper" style="<%= "display:none" if @post.comments.none? %>"> 
  <hr>
  <h2 class="center">COMMENTS</h2>
    <div id="post_show_comments">
      <%= render @comments %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the view

```
# comments/create.js.erb
$('#post_show_comments_wrapper').show();
$('#post_show_comments').append("<%= j render @comment %>");
```

Another option is to restructure the View UI so the comments header is showing and displays a "No comments yet" or "Enter the first comment" as a prompt along with the form.  Then, the empty div for the list would already be rendered and displayed normally.